# I am trying to recreate a simple helloworld machine learning example from a google youtube video, but I am getting errors that I do not understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to follow this machine learning hello world video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKxRvEZd3Mw
but I am getting errors that I do not understand. The errors seem to be within the library functions themselves and not with what I wrote directly. I know that the video is from 2016 so something must have changed in that time. I am just beginning with machine learning and need help!

I checked that the syntax is the same, don't know what else to do

```py
from sklearn import tree
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [[170, 0]]]
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print(clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```

the output in the video is "[1]", but I am getting these errors instead:

```
C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\helloWorld\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/offic/PycharmProjects/helloWorld/Hello World.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/offic/PycharmProjects/helloWorld/Hello World.py", line 5, in <module>
    clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
  File "C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\helloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 801, in fit
    X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
  File "C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\helloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 116, in fit
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
  File "C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\helloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 527, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\offic\PycharmProjects\helloWorld\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Remove the exceeding "[]" from "[[170, 0]]" in 'features'.

Comment: "The errors seem to be within the library functions themselves and not with what I wrote directly." - Just a piece of advice, its usually not the library's mistake, but yours. With big and trusted libraries such as sklearn, this is almost never the case.

Comment: @danlor thanks haha! I thought that my syntax was fine because I was using the autocomplete stuff and there were no squiggly lines, but I've never used python before!